# Endian reversal in padded scalar object

Tags: endianness

Using a GNU compiler on a Mac (I don't remember the versions) I encountered an implementation of type long double in which 16 bytes of storage were used but only 12 of them were used to represent the numeric value while the remaining 4 were merely padding for alignment.  If we assume that we are dealing with a little endian implementation and that the padding is in the highest-addressed 4 bytes, what should the 16 bytes contain if the endian were reversed?  Would the padding remain in the same 4 bytes and the reversal would occur only on the other 12 bytes or would reversal occur across all 16 bytes?

On a related note, if I have a long double (or any padded scalar) as described above will the padding bytes always occupy the highest byte addresses regardless of endianness?

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: The concept of endianness is harder to define for floating-point types than it is for integer types.

Comment: I don't see why this would be the case, but assuming that it is let's assume my questions above instead apply to a 16-byte integer type where 4 of the bytes are merely used for padding.

Comment: The reason is because a float is made up of three independent components.

Comment: But in that case couldn't the argument be made that a signed integer is made up of two independent components?